# How to solve this equation $\ x^2-y^2=29$

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics, symmetric-polynomials

How to find the solutions $\ (x,y)$ in  this equations

1.$\ x^2-y^2=29$

2.$\ x^2+xy+y^2=0$

any tricks plz

Comment: Integer solutions?

Comment: One may also interprent the question to mean solving the system of two equations for real $x,y$.

Comment: For 2. there is only one integer solution $(x,y) = (0,0)$.

Answer (score 5):

For the second equation, note that 
$$x^2+xy+y^2=\left(x+\frac y2\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}y^2$$

Answer (score 4):

This answer assumes you meant integer solutions.

**Hint:** For the first equation, $$(x-y)(x+y)=29$$ but 29 is a prime so one of both factors is equal to 1.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: For the second equation, assuming you meant real solutions.
$$x^2+xy+y^2=0\Rightarrow x^3-y^3=(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2)=0.$$
But $f(x)=x^3$ is injective. Hence, $x=y$. And thus $x=y=0$.

(Or note that $x^2+xy+y^2=(x+y/2)^2+3y^2/4$.)

Answer (score 0):

$ x^2 - y^2 = (x+y)(x-y)$

Note this is true for all factorisations of 29, but the only one that matters is 29*1, so solve for $x+y=29,  x-y=1$